# Is it possible to integrate Azure Event hub receiver with Flask and receive the data in flask?

Tags: python, azure, flask

I want to host the Azure event hub reader to a serverless server, but due to its listener behavior (continuously listening to events), the service seems to get timed out because it is expecting a response back from the receiver application. Is it possible to develop the receiver code in the flask and return a response back for each event?

[Event hub code from official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send#create-a-python-script-to-receive-events)

**The Ask: How to use the receiver of Azure Event Hub as a Flask API instead of a listener?**

Edit: Added the focusable point in "The Ask"